# Where does the packet cloned by iptables-mod-tee go after cloning?

Tags: linux, iptables, iptables-redirect

Were does the packed cloned by `iptables-mod-tee` go after cloning when I add a rule like this ?:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.3
```

Please refer to the diagram below.  I think it is obvious that with the command above, the `iptables-mod-tee` module uses the `POSTROUTING chain` of the `mangle table` as the cloning **source** but what happens with the packet **after** it is cloned ?  i.e. to which chain and table does the clone go to ?

[image]

EDIT: Added a red dashed line to the diagram above, to depict the cloned packet's path described in the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packet [cloned through TEE](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/netfilter/xt_TEE.c#L36), [is set to be untracked by conntrack](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_dup_ipv4.c#L72), [prevented from being](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_dup_ipv4.c#L90) [duplicated again](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_dup_ipv4.c#L58), and emitted through the [local output](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_dup_ipv4.c#L91) part of the routing stack, so first seen by raw/OUTPUT (you can also refer to this [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg): that would be right after the local process). This would be the same if the duplication was done before (eg in mangle or raw PREROUTING) for a routed packet. This makes it difficult (but [not impossible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553334/setting-up-udp-packets-to-two-different-destinations-using-iptables-and-prerouti/553707#553707)) to receive additional treatment like an additional nat, since it won't be tracked and it's difficult to distinguish it from the original.

Here's an example [TRACE](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#TRACE) (using iptables-legacy's version) capture in a setup similar to OP's of a ping made from 192.168.0.2 to 8.8.8.8: the capture was on the router using `iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -j TRACE`. The original *routed* packet will not appear since it would have to be captured from raw/PREROUTING, thus validating the explanation above telling it's done from output.

```
TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.0.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=39209 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3070 SEQ=1 
TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.0.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=39209 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3070 SEQ=1 
TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.0.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=39209 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3070 SEQ=1
```

Comment: You wrote that the cloned packet is "*emitted through the local output part of the routing stack*".
Does this mean that the cloned packet's path is as depicted by the red dashed line in the OP's edited diagram ?

Comment: Note that the source of these cloned packets is the outbound eth2 interface and their destination is the eth1 interface, so a loop should not happen.

Comment: Thanks, so the dashed red line correctly depicts the cloned packet's path, right? Also, please take a look at this related question:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553899/how-to-clone-the-output-of-the-masquerade-target-with-a-tee

Comment: yes (I changed my answer before to reflect this)

Comment: I added a comment on the other question. But I think this one is done, isn't it?