# Linux: UDP "multiplexer" inside kernel

Tags: networking, udp, forwarding, multicast

I have an application with very high performance requirements and the following job: There is incoming UDP traffic on port 1234. The packets have as fast as possible to be sent to hosts `H1`, `H2`, ... `Hn` where it must be possible to add or remove hosts at runtime. These hosts are not in the local network, but might even be in the internet.

I wanted to solve it with iptables / TEE, but I've found out that the used targets must be in the local network (or at most 1 hop away). So this did not work.

Generalizing https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553707/246665 for more than 2 targets also failed; and creating a network namespace per target host feels a bit over-engineered.

Does a solution exist to achieve this completely inside the kernel? Preferred with something "simple" like iptables and if not maybe with a kernel module?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1593995/iptables-nftables-forward-udp-data-to-multiple-targets (where I made an answer)

Comment: You are right; I thought I asked the question at the wrong place and therefore I've improved it and asked it on "superuser".